unable to define volume for Kafka configuration in order to start producer via CLI using docker
I have spawned multiple services as shown below using docker-compose.yml:

However, when I am trying to create a topic via CLI using the container-id it throws an error:
docker exec -it 09abca9e1aa4 /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic my-topicss

Error:
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh": stat /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh: no such file or directory: unknown

I researched and found some information about adding the volume to my Kafka service, but it also didn't work. Below is my code:
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.6.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.6.1
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    volumes:
      - ./broker/data:/opt/kafka

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.6.1
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.6.1
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'

I don't want to use any UI for generating topics and pushing data or such. Any hints will also be much appreciated.

Which container are you trying to use?  If it's the broker container (consider docker compose exec broker ...), the bind mount hides everything in /opt/kafka/bin in the image.  You probably want a different directory for the data storage.

Yes, I am using the broker container only. What should I change? @DavidMaze I am a newbie to such setups but trying my best to understand.

You're overriding /opt/kafka with the volume mount, so there wouldn't be a bin directory there. In any case, kafka-topics command should be available without the absolute path to the command

@OneCricketeer I even tried this docker exec -it 09abca9e1aa4 ./kafka-topics.sh but it failed with the same error.

I just tried to enter the shell of the zookeeper and broker(Kafka) and I found there are no files or any folders under that image. Do I need to setup something explicitly?

You don't need to use a relative path either. Just do docker exec -it 09abca9e1aa4 kafka-topics.

Yeah, thanks it worked. Can you post it as an answer?

@OneCricketeer Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78394101/schema-validation-with-pyflink-and-kafkas-schema-registry
