Schema Validation with Pyflink and Kafka's Schema Registry
I was able register my expected schema for the Kafka topic for the records arriving using the below command:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
  --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"UserData\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"user_id\",\"type\":\"int\"},{\"name\":\"transaction_timestamp_millis\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"currency\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"counterpart_id\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}"}' \
  http://localhost:8081/subjects/user-data/versions  

Now, I am trying to validate the incoming record values with the already registered schema. So, I tried this:
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json" \
  --data '{"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"UserData\",\"namespace\":\"io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"user_id\",\"type\":\"float\"},{\"name\":\"transaction_timestamp_millis\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"double\"},{\"name\":\"currency\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"counterpart_id\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}"}' \
  http://localhost:8081/compatibility/subjects/user-data/versions/latest

But it gives me the below response:
{"is_compatible":true}  

I was expecting it as false since the data type for the user_id field passed in the new request is float but I was expecting it to be int.
But since I want to validate my incoming record for the expected schema so I tried second approach and referred to this link
docker exec -it 5a7990c6f769 kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic lets-tests --config confluent.value.schema.validation=true --config confluent.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.user-data

But it gives me the below error:
Error while executing topic command : The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request.
[2024-04-27 06:51:34,766] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request.
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)

I have ensured that all the services are up and running except ksql and relevant services.
Also, my expectation is I don't want to terminate my producer session if the incoming record is not as per the expectation. Since I am using PyFlink, I was planning to park such records aside and send them to another topic that can be evaluated later. I can do this validation on the consumer side but how can I use schema registry efficiently for this purpose?
So where am I going wrong? What could be the best way here? Any help is much appreciated. TIA

I get that schema registry won't perform any validations on its own. Then why do those config parameters exist?

Is it to ensure schema validation on write-to-topics?

I also see that there is no way I can deserialize for avro as per this link https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#deserializer So do I need to write some custom logic that will parse the string value and then do the comparisons as per the schema from schema registry?

Flink has a Confluent Avro deserializer. Regarding the error in the question io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.user-data isn't a valid Java class name of a Strategy such as TopicNameStrategy. So the subject of the user-data topic values would then be user-data-value

What exactly can be done? How can I use a deserializer on the consumer side? Also, if a record being consumed is not as per the expectation then the pipeline shouldn't break. I am expecting it to park aside like by using the side-outputs of Flink. @OneCricketeer

I'm not familiar with Flink, but the format dependency is listed here https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.19/docs/connectors/table/formats/avro-confluent/

But what about the not-breaking part? If the schema is not as expected my code will break if I use deserializer. right?  Also, I can use the JAR and deserialize the records but right now I am not producing records in the serialized form by applying any serializers. Sorry for the naive questions but this is a little bit confusing for me @OneCricketeer.

If you enable schema validation on the broker, I believe it's the producer that would fail (the broker would reject the message). So, in theory, the consumer would never fail in that case. Otherwise, without the validation, yes, you'll need to implement some error handling on the deserializer, but I'm not familiar with concept of "side outputs"

side-outputs are nothing but segregating streams. It could be used for late-arriving data, good records stream, bad records stream, and so on. My question is if I implement any deserializer on the consumer side and if a bad record arrives then even the consumer will raise an exception and terminate right? @OneCricketeer
